# How to write a SOQL Query in Apex to Fetch the minimum amount of all the related opportunities for an account

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, aggregateresult

I have an account which has related opportunities. For those opportunities I wish to get the minimum amount through a SOQL Query. How can I achieve this if I need to use only 1 SOQL Statement in Apex?

I tried the following:

```
set<ID> setId = new Set<ID>();
List<Opportunities> oppList = [Select Id, Name, Amount from Opportunity Where Account.Name = 'Test Account 1'];

for(Opportunity opp: oppList){
setId.add(opp.id);
}

AggregateResult[] grp = [Select MIN(Amount) minAmt from Opportunity Where ID IN: setId];

for(AggregateResult agg: grp){
System.debug('Minimum is' + agg.get('minAmt');
}
```

I tried something like this but Im unable to convert it into a single SOQL Query.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Check out [ask] and [help/on-topic], then make an [edit] to add details.

Comment: Added the details. Im unable to convert it into a Single SOQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = [SELECT MIN(Amount) minAmt FROM Opportunity 
                                             WHERE Account.Name = 'Test Account 1' 
                                             GROUP BY Account.Name];

for(AggregateResult aggregateResult: aggregateResults){
    System.debug('Minimum is' + aggregateResult.get('minAmt'));
}
```